# How to append formatted string in C?

Tags: c

Below is what I have for now. What I am doing is to convert int to char or to do something like the toString function in Java. When appending the string and outputting it, it only shows 9 instead of 99. Is there a better way to do this since I understand that the formatted char length should be 2 thus it only showing one value as the end result?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
        
int main(void)
{
    int s = 99;
    char text[20];
    sprintf(text, "%d", s);
    char a[20];
    strncat(a,text,1);
    printf("\nYou have entered: %s", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the `1` means in this expression? `strncat(a,text,1);` Since `a` is uninitialized you should generally use `strcpy` to copy to it. `strcat` will look for the end of the existing string first, and there's no guarantee that it will find it within an uninitialized array.

Comment: `sprintf(text, "%d", s)` is the correct way of implementation. If you want to display a n-digit number (positive number) make sure you create a character array of n+1 size.(including the '\0' string termination). I have no idea why you have used `strncat(a,text,1)` here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and please read "[ask]". -- Would you mind to [edit] your question and add what you want to achieve with `strncat(a,text,1);`?

Answer (score 0):

Some things to note:

- You should initialize your `char a[20]` string because `strncat` looks for the end of the receiving string
- When using `strncat`, the third argument is the size of the string you are concatenating. Alternatively, use `strcat` which does not need you to specify the length of the string being added.

Here is your code modified to perform the task, you were almost there:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    
    int s = 99;
    char text[20];
    sprintf(text, "%d", s);
    
    char a[20] = "";
    strncat(a,text,strlen(text));
    // or:
    // strcat(a,text);
    printf("You have entered: %s", a);

    return 0;
}
```